# Why Natural Join and Inner Join Results Different in my query in SqlDeveloper?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, natural-join

I ran the queries in below in order to display the last name, 
job, department number, and department name for all employees who work in 
Toronto.

Table Structure is like this

- Employees(employee_id,last_name,department_id,...)
- Departments(department_id,department_name,location_id...)
- Locations(location_id,city,...)

With ON and USING clause it returns two results of row and

With NATURAL JOIN clause it returns only one.

What is the difference, Do I query it with natural join wrong?

With ON

```
SELECT 
  e.last_name,
  e.job_id,
  d.department_name, 
  l.city
FROM employees e 
  JOIN departments d ON e.department_id= d.department_id
  JOIN locations l ON d.location_id=l.location_id
WHERE upper(l.city)='TORONTO';
```

With USING

```
SELECT 
  e.last_name,
  e.job_id,
  d.department_name, 
  l.city
FROM employees e 
  JOIN departments d USING(department_id)
  JOIN locations l USING(location_id)
WHERE upper(l.city)='TORONTO';
```

With NATURAL JOIN

```
SELECT 
  last_name,
  job_id, 
  department_name, 
  city
FROM employees 
  NATURAL JOIN departments
  NATURAL JOIN locations
WHERE upper(city)='TORONTO';
```

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` is dangerous because it simply joins all matching column names, check your table definitions if additional duplicate column names exist in both tables

Comment: It's the `...` in your table definitions above where the answer lies, but the fact that you're getting fewer records with the `NATURAL JOIN` indicates there is indeed another common field between the tables that you're not using in your explicit joins.

Comment: You don't say what the rule is for a row to be in your result, so how can we tell you what query expressions are ok? Your queries do not have the same meaning. If one doesn't return what you expect, tell us what you expect & why--refer to the manual--we can say where you went wrong. Otherwise you are just asking us to rewrite the manual. Also: [mcve]

Answer (score 4):

Im guessing you are using the HR schema in oracle. both employees and department have a field mangager_id which you are not joining on. but the natural join will join on them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, 

i can not use natural join to get the correct result right ?

Comment: natural join behaves like this ? looks for common columns and found 2 columns, it evaluates like combined unique key, then check corresponding results in other table.
   if so, it checks for manager_id from departments table not employees because of not used qualifier(table alias) in my case i think.. 
   i queried for d.manager_id with ON clause, the result is:
   
   (manager_id department_id)
   (201   20),
   (201   20)     
   
   for e.manager_id with ON clause, the result is:
   
   (manager_id department_id)
   (100   20),
   (201   20)

Comment: In a result i must not use natural join if i have more than 1 common column right ?

Comment: it will join on columns that are named the same.  I generally stay away from natural join because when  new columns are  added to  tables queries may stop working

Comment: Thanks for your helpfulness.Have a nice coding

Comment: Actually I miss Oracle took a new job for a .net front end to a mainframe cobol app and the database is DB2 Yeck